# I'm not getting an error message in my qsub error log even though I'm running into an error

Tags: r, cluster-computing, sh, qsub, rscript

Here is my .sh script

```
#PBS -N Polygenic
#PBS -S /bin/bash
#PBS -l walltime=8:00:00
#PBS -l nodes=1:ppn=8
#PBS -l mem=4gb
#PBS -o $HOME/${PBS_JOBNAME}.o${PBS_JOBID}.log
#PBS -e $HOME/${PBS_JOBNAME}.e${PBS_JOBID}.err

module load R
Rscript /group/stranger-lab/ebeiter/PolygenicAdaptationCode-master/Example/Run_Files/exampleHeightRunFile.R
```

I know that my Rscript is running into an error at line 71 out of 390 because I have run it outside of the cluster and it stops then. But when I look into my error log, it's completely blank. The job takes about 6 hours to run and what I've been doing is just running it on my 4GB Ram Macbook but that is taking so much time and the pipe is breaking to my shell and I'm timing out. I want to submit it as a job to the cluster as a qsub but I'm not getting any feedback on the errors in my log so I can't do that. What is going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest redirect errors from Rscript.  I run it like

```
Rscript >>output.txt 2>&1 script.R
```

in the PBS script.  I suspect Rscript errors are not caught by the scheduler.

Comment: Thanks! So just insert `>>output.txt 2>&1` before my script name and I'll get an output file with the error? What if the job runs smoothly, what will output be?

Comment: I tried this and I still didn't get anything in my error log or my output.txt file.

Comment: Hmm... But what do you get?  Try inserting a stop() command early in your script and check if you get the message.  If there are no errors, then you just get whatever the program outputs (potentially nothing).  You also get the system error messages.  What kind of error do you expect?

Comment: the error log and the output.txt.file were empty when i opened them. The program takes a really long time to run so I don't know what error I'm expecting. But I need to get an output. The program runs 6 hours in my ssh but then the pipe breaks so I have to find a way to use qsub but I don't get any error feedback

Comment: here is a similar post I made http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33138225/rscript-combined-with-sh-not-giving-me-an-output-error-log-blank. Maybe this will help you solve my issue

Comment: What does this mean: "then the pipe breaks"?  I had similar issues with SOCKET cluster (don't remember the exact error), switching to MPI cluster solved the issue

Comment: I use a university cluster. My job takes so long if I run it in the command prompt as an Rscript that I get an error saying I have a broken pipe.

Comment: Seems like your program crashes before you get to the error.

Comment: Seems like your program crashes before you get to the error.  Does your code invoke any parallel processing?  You seem to run only one instance through your pbs script but you ask for 8 processors.  

Does the cluster use some sort of pre-emption (killing and restarting your job every once and a while)?

Output debugging messages in the suspicious locations in your code.  Check if you can see those and where do they stop.

Comment: I don't run the code in the command prompt as I meantioned above. When I qsub it, the pipe does not break

Comment: The code in the qsub takes only 8 minutes. It get's far into the program because it's making some directories that I ask for in the code pretty far into it

Comment: i'm starting to remember I had this issue a few months ago. It's a memory thing I think. I was at 4gb for another job and I bumped it up to 64gb (a few months ago) and it solved my problem. I'm trying that now. Is there anyway to tell how much memory my job will need?

Comment: I don't think so.  I would recommend to print out memory usage at various stages of your program to get an idea.  In this way you may be able to predict it.  You can also set limits on memory (in the bps script) and check where do these bite.  You can run it, and then ssh into the computing node and check the need through top.

Comment: Where would the printed out memory usage be if the program never finishes? Would it be in the log? Or wherE?

Comment: if you `print(gc())` the output goes wherever the other output goes.  Now I have little idea how your code works, but printing various diagnostics messages in the places where you suspect the code dies is a good point to start.